# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function in ReactJs but it's indeed a Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
ShipIndicatorsCharts
C:/DTI/VLIRepos/ConectaRepos/COM.PortalPosVenda.FrontEnd/src/common/components/Organisms/Ports/ShipIndicatorsCharts/index.js:8
   5 | import { getLastThreeMonths } from './helper';
   6 | import { ChartsContainer } from './styles';
   7 | 
>  8 | function ShipIndicatorsCharts() {
   9 |   const [showShipIndicators, setShowShipIndicators] = useState(null);
  10 |   const {
  11 |     shipIndicatorsClientMonth,
```

The error is referencing this file:

```
import React, { useState, useSelector } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { loadShipIndicatorsClientMonth } from 'common/ducks/ports/shipIndicators';
import ShipIndicatorsMonthlyClientChart from 'common/components/Organisms/Ports/ShipIndicatorsCharts/ShipIndicatorsMonthlyClientChart';
import { getLastThreeMonths } from './helper';
import { ChartsContainer } from './styles';

function ShipIndicatorsCharts() {
  const [showShipIndicators, setShowShipIndicators] = useState(null);
  const {
    shipIndicatorsClientMonth,
    loadingShipIndicatorsClientMonth,
    errorShipIndicatorsClientMonth,
  } = useSelector((store) => store.ports);

  var clientCnpjs = [
    '47080619000974',
    '47080619003051',
    '47080619003302',
    '47080619006239',
    '47080619001199',
    '47080619006158',
    '26203671000143',
    '05242560000176',
    '37456919000102',
    '47080619000117'
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadShipIndicatorsClientMonth(
      2, getLastThreeMonths(), clientCnpjs
    ));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowShipIndicators(shipIndicatorsClientMonth);
  }, [shipIndicatorsClientMonth]);
  const isDataNull = (showShipIndicators == null);

  return (
    <ChartsContainer>
      {(!isDataNull) && showShipIndicators.map(indicator => {
        <ShipIndicatorsMonthlyClientChart
          year={indicator.year}
          month={indicator.month}
          clients={indicator.clients}
        />
      })};
      {(isDataNull) && (
        <EmptyChartCard>
          <EmptyState
            description='Não há dados para o período'
          />
        </EmptyChartCard>
      )};
    </ChartsContainer>
  );
}

export default ShipIndicatorsCharts;
```

And this file is imported here:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { getUserIdExternal, getUserNameExternal } from 'common/utils/userUtil';
import { eventRegister } from 'config/appInsights';
import { events } from 'common/utils/events';
import ShipIndicators from 'common/components/Organisms/Ports/ShipIndicators';
import ShipIndicatorsCharts from 'common/components/Organisms/Ports/ShipIndicatorsCharts';
import { PortsTemplate } from './styles';

function Ports() {
  const [isloaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isloaded) {
      eventRegister(
        events.acesso_indicadores_portuarios,
        getUserIdExternal(),
        getUserNameExternal(),
        window.location.pathname,
      );
      setLoaded(true);
    }
  });

  return (
    <PortsTemplate>
      <ShipIndicators />
      <ShipIndicatorsCharts />
    </PortsTemplate>
  );
}

export default Ports;
```

To me it seems like I correctly defined and imported my file, i know that ShipIndicatorsCharts is indeed a function, i also know that the path to the file is correct because ShipIndicators is being imported normally, i tried restarting yarn but to no avail, what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your `ShipIndicatorsCharts` `.js` or `.jsx`?  make sure it's jsx...

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas it's not .jsx but the shipIndicatos is and its importing is fine,

Comment: It should be .jsx if it's using React for rendernig.

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas changing to .jsx doesnt fix the error :/